# WPF Simple Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to convert my console app to a nice WPF GUI. Am getting a little stuck on this code and was wondering if someone can help?

In my xaml I have this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CL.LoggedIn}"></CheckBox>
```

to try and bind the value of the checkbox to the value of CL.LoggedIn. CL is my ConnectionLibrary.cs class in a referenced class library.

In the code behind for the xaml page i declare CL as follows :

```
public ConnectionLibrary CL = new ConnectionLibrary();
```

In the connection library class I have added :INotifyPropertyChanged to the class declaration and added the following code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

I have changed the LoggedIn property to now look like this:

```
private bool loggedIn;
public bool LoggedIn { 
    get { return loggedIn; } 
    set { loggedIn = value; OnPropertyChanged("LoggedIn"); }
}
```

However, it doesnt seem to work in my xaml? I dont get any binding errors in the output window, but it doesnt reflect the value of LoggedIn correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use public fields, as you do with `CL`.

Comment: Read the [data binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the datacontext of your view?
In the code-behind of your XAML file, you need to do:

```
this.DataContext = CL;
```

then the binding is:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding LoggedIn}"></CheckBox>
```

The binding will find the the named path (i.e. LoggedIn) on the object that is in the DataContext.

**EDIT**: The default binding is one-way, this means it only gets updated from your ViewModel.
For controls that can be inputed data (i.e: TextBox, CheckBox...) you can set the Binding as "TwoWay". The Binding expression becomes:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding LoggedIn, Mode="TwoWay"}"></CheckBox>
```

Now whenever the Checked state changes in the UI, it is reflected in your ViewModel.

Comment: Excellent - I was just reading the code to find where datacontext was set and here it is :=)

Comment: Say I want to keep the datacontext to just the codebehind file as I want to aggregate data into it from a few other classes. How would I link in to CL.LoggedIn then and keep the binding working whenever the property changes??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking in your last comment. Your code-behind should be clean, just set the datacontext. The logic should be in your ViewModel (and it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged). See my updated answer for two-way binding.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Binding` like this, it binds to the current `DataContext`, not to the page itself.

The easiest way to fix this would be to set `DataContext = this` at the end of the constructor of the page.

The proper way to fix it would be to use [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). That would mean having `ConnectionLibrary` in a property of another class and set the `DataContext` to this other class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding LoggedIn}"></CheckBox>
```